# Checking for membership in dictionary: exceptions or set?

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I want to process a list of elements `ls`, each of which may or may not have a corresponding element in a dictionary `d`. I can think of two ways to do it. Here, `s` is the set of all elements that are keys of `d`. When constructing `d` it is trivial to construct `s` as well, so take that as given.

```
for e in ls:
    if e in s:
        process(d[e])
```

and

```
for e in ls:
    try:
        process(d[e])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Of the two, which is faster? Furthermore I've heard that Python uses the principle of "Ask forgiveness, not permission". Does this mean that in general testing using `if` statements will be slower than using exceptions?

Comment: And which one is faster depends on the frequency of misses, see [Python Forgiveness vs. Permission and Duck Typing](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/175655/175663#175663). Loads of misses: use `in` testing. Few misses: use exceptions.

Comment: Does the order in which you process `ls` elements important?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, it does not.

Comment: Does it matter which is faster? Assuming that your `process` method does some real work, I'd guess that the running time of that method will totally dwarf any difference between the two approaches.

Comment: @MarkByers Probably true, but I'd still like to know out of curiosity and to know how Python does things.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the link to that other question, helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If order doesn't matter, use intersections:

```
for e in s.intersection(ls):
    # only elements that are in `s` *and* `ls` are iterated over
    process(d[e])
```

Most of your time is probably going to be spent in `process()` in any case, so don't micro-optimize. Instead optimize for readability (within reason).

As for the choice of `in` test vs. exception handling: exception handling will be faster if the number of misses is low (relatively few exceptions), but if you have a lot of misses the `in` test will be faster than handling loads of exceptions. If you really care, use the  [`timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to find a balance. See [my answer on the subject on Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175655/175663#175663).